# Custom Links in Walker Class

Tags: php, menus, walker

I am creating a custom walker class.

I need to identify the custom links that will be added to the menu from **Appearace > Menu > Custom Link**

so that they will have a different format to the page/post links

Any thoughts on how I can do this within walker class possibly using if statement?

something like

```
if (link = custom-link) {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test for …

```
$item->object = 'custom'
```

This is used for custom links only. `$item->object` is always the post type or the item *type* (`category` for example). Not sure what happens when someone registers a custom post type named `custom` :)